# Перемешивание индексов и вывод значения

Tags: delphi, массивы

Пишу программу на делфи, массив а - массив строк, нужно перекинуть индексы массива в другой массив, перемешать, но вывести в мемо строки, соответствующие индексам (перемешанным). Помогите, пожалуйста, с реализацией кода.

Comment: Начните хотя бы. Создайте массивы, киньте на форму Мемо, кнопку "Перемешать". Задача-то тривиальная. Когда появятся конкретные вопросы - пишите сюда.

Comment: Так это уже сделано


здесь строки преобразуются в массив, далее массив перемешивается, и выводится в мемо2.. вообще задание состоит в том, чтобы сгенерировать билеты по списку вопросов, на каждый билет по 3 вопроса, и чтобы вопросы в билете шли по увеличению своего номера в первичном списке.    и когда я делю перемешанный массив по 3 вопроса.. то я не смогу сортировать по первичным индексам.. то есть какой алгоритм нужен ? чтобы индексы первого мссива сохранялись и они перемешивались..и выводить их значение

Answer (score 1):

Для перемешивания воспользуйтесь алгоритмом Фишера-Йейтса.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял, проблемы с перемешиванием индексов. Моя идея такова: генерировать в цикле случайные числа (от 0 - до наибольшего индекса), затем проверять входят ли они во множество, и если нет, то включать во множество и выскакивать из цикла (Repeat .. Until).
Вот Вам пример консольной программы, которая перемешивает массив индексов:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

Var
  IndSet: Set Of Byte;
  MasInd: Array[0..99] Of Byte;
  i: Byte;

begin
  Randomize;
  For i:=0 To 14 Do
     MasInd[i]:=i;

  For i:=0 To 14 Do
    Begin
      Repeat
        MasInd[i]:=Random(15);
        If Not(MasInd[i] In IndSet) Then
          Begin
            Include(IndSet, MasInd[i]);
            Break;
          End;
      Until (False);
    End;

  WriteLn;
  WriteLn;

  For i:=0 To 14 Do
    WriteLn(MasInd[i]);

  ReadLn;
end.
```

**Этот вариант не подойдёт, если в Вашем массиве более чем 255 элементов.**

Answer (score 0):

Вам проще завести новый класс, например:

```
type
  TMyString = class(TObject)
  public
    OldIndex: Integer;
    S: String;
  end;
```

Далее завести переменную массив наших строк:

```
var MyStrings: array of TMyString;
```

далее забираем строки из мемо:

```
SetLength(MyStrings, Length(a));
for I:= 0 to Length(a) - 1 do
begin
  MyStrings[I]:= TMyString.Create;
  MyStrings[I].OldIndex:= I;
  MyStrings[I].S:= a[I];    
end;
```

Теперь вы можете перемешивать массив MyStrings как вам угодно, порядок, в котором строки шли в массиве a мы запомнили. 
После этого выводите в мемо:

```
for I:= 0 to Length(MyStrings) - 1 do
  Memo1.Lines.Add(MyStrings[I].S);
```

В конце не забудем убить объекты:

```
for I:= 0 to Length(MyStrings) - 1 do
  MyStrings[I].Free;
```

Comment: А почему не `record`?

Comment: Спасибо большое, пробую.. и еще один вопрос.. если я укажу в перемешивание.. что индекс первого массива дожен отличаться от следующего не меньше чем на 4, то не будет ли зацикливания ?

Comment: > А почему не record?
как показывает практика, если вы потом развиваете проект, меньше переделок понадобится, если сразу сделать классы.
> не будет ли зацикливания ?
ну это от алгоритма перемешивания зависит... на самом деле я бы не стал делать доп условий, так как уже будет перемешивание не совсем случайное

Comment: просто по заданию строки не должны быть близки друг к другу(в первом массиве)..